# Existing object suddenly become null. Cannot generate print preview from database. C#

Tags: c#, database

I am writing a database management GUI for a company. There are several forms and they are binding to a database created from Access. Forms are like Employer, Vacancies and so on.

I am writing a function to generate and print all Vacancies information. One Vacancy each page. I am using some Currency manager to control where to find the `vacancyID` from Vacancy table.

```
// get the Vacancy record matching the Vacancy ID from the Vacancy record
int aVanID = Convert.ToInt32(drVanReport["VacancyID"].ToString());
cmVacancy.Position = DM.VacancyView.Find(aVanID);   
//As soom as the app run at this line, ERROR HAPPENED.         

DataRow drVan = DM.dtVacancy.Rows[cmVacancy.Position];
```

Then I use `Graphics g = e.Graphics; g.drawing` to generate my document for print preview.

```
private void btnVacancies_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (vacancies == null)
    {
        vacancies = new Vacancies(DM, this);
    }
    vacancies.ShowDialog(); 
    //ERROR POINTED TO HERE! SAYING Object reference not set to an instance of an object.     
}
```

This error should not happen?? My codes is not actually about opening this form, although my button is on this form. This form is surely existing and opened successfully just now. Why is it null now?? I used `try..catch..throw` it too. But my document still cannot generate any data for print preview.

Can someone tell me how should I adjust my code to avoid this error and generate printing preview successfully? Thanks.

Maybe only some one who has ever done similar application could understand the context.

Comment: Why is the initial error relevant? If it is you should include how you handle the error and how it's related to the vacancies object. I have some ideas on how this could happen, but need some more details.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please post the full error message. Also, post a [minimum verifiable code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). As a first guess, your `new Vacancies()` may be returning a `null`. Do a `Debug.Assert(vacancies != null)` to verify this. But the real issue may be in the constructor of Vacancies or the way you are calling it.

Comment: Often the null is something other than what you think is obvious. If its this line `cmVacancy.Position = DM.VacancyView.Find(aVanID)` then it could be cmVacancy, cmVacancy.Position, DM, DM.VacancyView, or aVanID.